# Splitlines inside a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a log file of the format :

```
2010-06-26T10:15:25.4561Z, Some stuff here,...\n2010-06-26T10:15:28.4561Z, abcd,...\n2010-06-26T10:15:30.4561Z, asdasd,...\n2010-06-26T10:15:45.4561Z, qwertqwert,...\n2010-06-26T10:16:25.4561Z, xcvbn,...\n2010-06-26T10:17:25.4561Z, Some random event,...\n2010-06-26T10:19:25.4561Z, logs,...\n2010-06-26T10:22:25.4561Z, logssssss,...\n
```

How do read these lines as separate lines in python without \n

Comment: ``text.splitlines()`` should do it.

Comment: For each line call `line.strip()` which takes away the whitespace from both ends.

Comment: Is that `\n` (two characters) or a newline?

Comment: The log file is very big and it contains \n as the sole indicator that a new line is starting.

Answer (score 0):

Use splitlines as follows:

```
log = "...."
for line in log.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

I you want to split on some other character you can do like this:

```
log = "...."
for line in log.split('foo'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use readlines by just using \n as an indiactor that a new line is starting

Comment: Updated answer if you split on something else.